# zf & PHP unrecognized in spite of setting Environment Variables

Tags: php, zend-framework, wamp

Iam installing zend on my Windows machine using WAMP with the help of [this youtube tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m7svJHmgJqs) However , i went to My Computer -> Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables and Edited "PATH". Currently it looks like this :

> %SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;C:\Program
>   Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13;C:\wamp\bin\php\zend_framework\bin;

I have copied my zend to C:\wamp\bin\php just like the tutorial does

However iam getting

> 'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

for both **zf** and **php -v** on cmd

Please help iv been stuck on this for over 2 days

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think we need to focus first on PHP. ZF can follow after.

A failure of `php -v` means that none of the directories in your `PATH` contain the executable `php.exe`. So, first thing is to find the directory containing that executable and make sure that it appears in your `PATH` variable (as set in `My Computer -> Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables`. Remember to start a new terminal session every time you change it. An updated `PATH` will not be magically imported into an existing terminal session.)

A similar thing for ZF. Find the `zf.bat` file from your ZF distribution and make sure the containing directory appears in the `PATH`.

Note: On Windows, I found that I often had to invoke the ZF command-line script using `zf.bat`. YMMV.